# Is HealthIndicator thread safe?

Tags: spring-boot, health-check

Do I have to make the method `check()` thread-safe?

```
@Component
public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Autowired
    private MyComponent myComponent;

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        int errorCode = myComponent.check();
        if (errorCode != 0) {
            return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

Is the request to the corresponding actuator endpoint executed in a separated thread?
The app logic itself has only one thread.

Comment: It runs in a different thread. The webserver you are using (which is embedded by spring boot) will create a number of threads to process requests concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the direct question you asked ...

> Do I have to make the method check() thread-safe?

You don't *have* to make it thread-safe, but if your application **requires** that `myComponent.check()` is only executed by a single thread at once, then yes, you'll need to mark it `synchronized`.

To answer the more general question

> Is HealthIndicator thread safe?

By default, each health check initiated (often by an HTTP call, perhaps to `/actuator/health`) will run on a single thread, and check the health of each component that's registered a `HealthIndicator` sequentially, and thus the individual request is single-threaded.

HOWEVER ... there's nothing to stop multiple clients each making a request to `/actuator/health` at the same time, and thus there *may* be multiple health checks in progress at the same time, each of which will be executing on a different thread.

Therefore, if there's some reason why `myComponent.check()` should *not* be executed by more than one thread concurrently, you will need to mark it `synchronized` or else add in some other concurrency limiting mechanisms (e.g. `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`).